# how to read axis ticks from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have a file with histogram which I want to draw. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % for histograms

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ height = 0.4\paperheight
                , width = 0.7\paperwidth
                ]

        \addplot [ybar interval, color = black, fill = blue, line width = 0.5mm] 
            table {hist1.data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can I set x and y ticks to values in file?
Like that (dots are not required):
[image: example]

File "hist1.data":

```
 1 0.06
 3 0.23
 5 0.35
 7 0.2
 9 0.1
 11 0.04
 13 0.01
 15 0
 17 0
 19 0.01
 21 0
```

I'm sorry if it is duplicated question, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `ytick=data,xtick=data`, the ticks will be placed at the y- and x-values used in the first `\addplot`. And with `extra y ticks={0,0.05,...,0.35}` you get the default ticks as well. (Of course with different data, you have to change the values. The two numbers before `...` is the first two values in the list, and the step is the difference between them. The list stops at the number after `...`.)

The `filecontents` stuff is only used to make the example self-contained, you don't need it for your own use, as you already have the `hist1.data` file.

The `yticklabel style` is used to get `0.06` instead of `6\cdot10^{-2}` as the ticklabel.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % for histograms
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{hist1.data}
 1 0.06
 3 0.23
 5 0.35
 7 0.2
 9 0.1
 11 0.04
 13 0.01
 15 0
 17 0
 19 0.01
 21 0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
  height = 0.4\paperheight,
  width = 0.7\paperwidth,
  extra y ticks={0,0.05,...,0.35},
  ytick=data,xtick=data,
  yticklabel style={
   /pgf/number format/fixed,
   /pgf/number format/precision=2,
  }
]

 \addplot [ybar interval, color = black, fill = blue, line width = 0.5mm] 
            table {hist1.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if you don't mind, can I ask one more question? Is it possible to save old ticks and draw "ytick=data" at the same time? In any case thank you very  much!

Comment: @ВячеславРадько See updated answer.